# Assigning "None" to a function that requires transfer parameters (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

I'm struggling at assigning "None" values to all parameter of a function.

```
for i in range(18):
    sx.set_attribute(v{i}=None)
```

The attributes I want to fill with "None" are v0 -> v18
I'm only looking for the right syntax.
If you know a better way to assign "None" values to vars that do not contain values, present it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a dictionary with function parameters(`v0 -> v18`) as keys and value as `None`. Then use [`**` to unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) the dictionary as function arguments.

```
sx.set_attribute(**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(18)})
```

Comment: @mathandlogic it's inappropriate to request that people upvote your posts. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323847/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-a-question

Comment: how can I add an if condition that makes this only then assign "None" when the var does not contain a value? I tried the following: `sx.set_attribute(v1=3,**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(19) if f"v{i}" is ""}`